# using grep in bash scripting

Tags: bash, grep

I'm writing a bash script in Ubuntu. I use `grep` inside:

```
resultfolder=$(grep 'ResultsFolder' "$clientConfig" | cut -f2 -d '=')
```

Hereby, clientConfig is the absolute path to A file where I want to search for the String 'resultsFolder'.
While executing, he give me the error: No such file or directory.

But I can execute this command in the terminal without any fault. Is this because he uses `$clientConfig` before he actually knows this? And how can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Give more context please. What is in `$clientConfig`, a file name or what?

Comment: Are you mention the file for searching pattern?

Comment: Try printing the $clientConfig before running this command and see whether the $clientconfig contain files with path correctly

Comment: What exactly do you mean with 'Is this because he uses $clientConfig before he actually knows this?' ? Is $clientConfig set after the line with grep is executed? Also beware of the working directory if the $clientConfig is a relative path.

Comment: 'ResultsFoder' needs to be the search pattern. I also printed clientConfig and it gave me the true path. clientConfig is set before the line is executed. I wondered he fills this $clientConfig before he starts executing the script.

Answer (score 0):

You should just look at the value of $clientConfig
add an echo before the grep.
if $clientConfig is more than a single file you need to remove the double quotes (") around it.

```
echo \#$clientConfig; grep 'ResultsFolder' "$clientConfig" | cut -f2 -d '=')
```

Answer (score 0):

$clientConfig is one single file and `echo $clientConfig` gives me the next result:

```
/groups/wall2-ilabt-iminds-be/projectfilip/videostreaming/libdashclient/emulationclient/client_config.ini
```

This result is the correct path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
resultfolder=$(awk -F= '/ResultsFolder/ {print $2}' "$clientConfig")
```